# Drilling a tunnel into the core of Enceladus

Tags: science-based, space-colonization, geology, construction

The extreme pressure and temperature greatly reduces our ability to drill holes deeper than some kilometers into Earth's mantle.

However, on a body smaller, colder and less dense, this would be a significantly easier task.

**Could a human-supporting tunnel be built into the centre of Enceladus (Saturn's satellite) using near future tech (mainly present day materials)?**

Comment: No idea, but thanks for pointing out Enceladus. It is a fantastic moon.

Comment: See [Can lasers be used to drill holes or build tunnels?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/52407/can-lasers-be-used-to-drill-holes-or-build-tunnels) and [A: Establishing an under-ice base on Europa - ice drilling/melting?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/56575/establishing-an-under-ice-base-on-europa-ice-drilling-melting/56707#56707) for general information, much of which is applicable here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  First of all, you hit ocean under the ice, so you need a sealed tunnel there, not a hole.
[image: Map]

Although smaller than Earth, it is still warm enough to melt the magma, so you need a tunnel capable of keeping out thousand-degree melted rock.

Meanwhile, the ice and the mantle are in motion.  Any tunnel lining needs to hold back an enormous momentum.  Ever consider stopping a glacier?  This is orders of magnitude worse.

To reach the center, you need 250 km of tunnel, which doesn’t sound that bad.  But it is through layers that *move* and have (still) enormous pressure and temperature beyond any near-future material’s ability.

Comment: Yea the moving part would destroy the tunnel. Imagine millions of pounds of rock shifting. No tunnel could withstand that.

Comment: Millions of pounds is way to small in magnitude.  If rock is 2.5 grams per cubic cenimeter, a million pounds is on the order of a hundred cubic meters.  That's house sized, not continent sized!